# 404 redirect based on url

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess, 404-error

I have a link like this:

```
https://www.example.com/bh-job/38/?title=digital-marketing-intelligence-expert
```

When I surf to the page I'm redirected 404 page because the page doesn't exisit. The page doesn't exist but I would like to redirect to https://www.example.com/jobs instead.

I also have another page like this:

```
https://www.example.com/bh-job/121/?title=sem-manager
```

And this is an actual page and can be found.

So I would need a check where I redirect from the 404 page to **/jobs** page WHEN the link start with **https://www.example.com/bh-job/** and can't be found. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `wp` hook, which fires right after the request has been parsed and queried:

```
function wpse_199869_wp( $wp ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_404() && preg_match( '/^bh-job/', $wp->request ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( user_trailingslashit( 'jobs' ) ) );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'wpse_199869_wp' );
```

We make sure it's a 404, and check if the request (URI path) begins with `bh-job` - if so, redirect to `/jobs` (the `user_trailingslashit` function will append or remove a trailing slash to match your permalink structure).